# UITextView text highlighting when the text is centered

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I use the following code to highlight text in my `UITextView` - every time the text changes, I convert it into an `NSMutableAttributedString` so I can center it, add the highlight and set the font.

**Creating the `UITextView`**

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 300, 100)];
textView.center = self.view.center;
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"RopaSans-Italic" size:30];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
textView.text = [@"" uppercaseString];
textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

**Delegate method**

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    textView.text = [textView.text uppercaseString];
    NSString *string = textView.text;

    NSMutableAttributedString *att = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    paragrapStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    [att addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:[textView.text rangeOfString:textView.text]];
    [att addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:[textView.text rangeOfString:textView.text]];
    [att addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"RopaSans-Italic" size:30] range:[textView.text rangeOfString:textView.text]];
    [att addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:[textView.text rangeOfString:textView.text]];

    //Find all occurencies of newline
    NSString *substring = @"\n";
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0,string.length);
    NSRange foundRange;
    while (searchRange.location < string.length) {
        searchRange.length = string.length-searchRange.location;
        foundRange = [string rangeOfString:substring options:nil range:searchRange];
        if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) {

            [att addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:foundRange];

            searchRange.location = foundRange.location+foundRange.length;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    textView.attributedText = att;

}
```

However, when the text starts to be too long to fit into the `UITextView` and the cursor jumps into the next line, the background is coloured even when there is no text there (see figure 1). The same happens when the user hits the enter button and jumps into the next line (see figure 1). However, I was able to "override" that by looking for all \n characters' ranges in the string and changing the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` for that range to `[UIColor clearColor]`. The effect was as in figure 2. I've tried to do the same with all line breaks (\r and \r\n), however it did't work, so I'm now stuck with a `UITextView`, which kinda does what I want unless the user doesn't use "Enter" to hop into the next line.

How can I fix this?
[image: Figure 1][image: Figure 2]

Comment: Did u figure it out?